# How to make a c# program that responds to syslog events on ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04?

Tags: c#, ubuntu, .net-core, syslog

My solution to responding to syslog events stops working after several hours. I was running 'tail -f' from C# and subscribing to DataReceived events. My issue is that after several hours it seems to just stop working without throwing errors or exiting the process. I think this happens when the syslog file rolls over.

Current solution that stops working after many hours:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;
using App.Configuration;
using App.LogData;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace IQIngest.SrtWatch.Services
{
    public class SyslogReaderService
    {
        private ILogger<SyslogReaderService> _logger;
        private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;
        private IOptionsSnapshot<AppSettings> _appSettings;
        private ITargetBlock<string> _targetQueue;
        public SyslogReaderService(ILogger<SyslogReaderService> logger,
        CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource,
        IOptionsSnapshot<AppSettings> appSettings,
        ITargetBlock<string> targetQueue)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _cancellationTokenSource = cancellationTokenSource;
            _appSettings = appSettings;
            _targetQueue = targetQueue;
        }

        public async Task StartReader()
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo($"/usr/bin/tail", $"-f {_appSettings.Value.TailedFile}")
            {
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true
            };
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    using (Process tail = new Process()
                    {
                        StartInfo = startInfo
                    })
                    {
                        _cancellationTokenSource.Token.Register(tail.Kill);
                        tail.OutputDataReceived += handleLine;
                        tail.ErrorDataReceived += handleLine;
                        tail.Start();
                        _logger.LogDebug($"Started tail process for file {{@{LogFields.FILENAME_STR}}}.", _appSettings.Value.TailedFile);
                        tail.BeginOutputReadLine();
                        tail.BeginErrorReadLine();
                        tail.WaitForExit();
                        //Stops working and doesn't make it to this line.
                        _logger.LogDebug($"Tail stopped.");
                        if (!_cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested) _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogError(ex, $"Unhandled exception thrown from {nameof(SyslogReaderService)}.");
                }
            });
        }

        private void handleLine(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            _logger.LogDebug($"Posting new line to internal processing queue.");
            _targetQueue.Post(e.Data);
        }
    }
}
```

If there is an obvious issue with my code above that would fix this issue then a simple solution to that would be great, however I am thinking that I may need to take a different approach.

First let me say my understanding of syslog is not very strong, but from what I understand you can configure syslog to forward events to a 'syslog server'. So I am thinking that I could configure syslog to send events to a localhost port and have my app respond to those events. With this solution I think I can bypass the uncertainty of tailing the file and also dealing with the rolling of the file if I just incrementally read and evaluate which lines are new. So if there isn't an obvious issue with my solution then how do I configure syslog to send copies of events to  my c# application running locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up configuring syslog to send events to a local udp port and then listened on that port on the c# side. Tailing the file was not the way to go.